# bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges mucking up

Tags: python, add-on

Dunno if I'm just a dummy or why this is happening, but every time I try to run the command it crashes Blender. What am I doing wrong?

```
class  SUBDIVIDE_OT_Vertexgroup(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "subdivide.vertexgroup"
    bl_label = "Bake Displace modifier"
    
    def execute(self,context):
       
        ob = bpy.context.active_object        
        mat = ob.active_material
        vertex_name = mat.extremepbr_material_prop.mat_id_name                      
        find = ob.vertex_groups.get(vertex_name)
                    
        if find:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') 
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_set_active(group=vertex_name)
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()            
            me = ob.data         
            bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)            
            border = [ e for e in bm.edges if e.select ]            
            bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(bm,
                    edges=border,
                    cuts=1,
                    use_grid_fill=True)
            me.update()
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()
    
        return{'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Hard to test without `vertex_name = mat.extremepbr_material_prop.mat_id_name`  But one glare-out is `me.update()` try replacing with `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Yep... thought I'd test it out. No idea why the downvote, here's an upvote from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `me.update` with `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)`

Made a MWE from question code and tested on default cube with a single face in vertex group named "Group".

Recommend adding imports and a default dummy setting, which will make it easier for answerers to test, answer.

An edit mode bemsh is "bound" to the mesh and rarely likes it if you try and do anything to the underlying mesh data while it is active.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

class  SUBDIVIDE_OT_Vertexgroup(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "subdivide.vertexgroup"
    bl_label = "Bake Displace modifier"
    
    def execute(self,context):
       
        ob = bpy.context.active_object        
        mat = ob.active_material
        vertex_name = "Group"                     
        vg = ob.vertex_groups.get(vertex_name)
                    
        if vg:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') 
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_set_active(group=vertex_name)
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()            
            me = ob.data         
            bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)            
            border = [ e for e in bm.edges if e.select ]            
            bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(bm,
                    edges=border,
                    cuts=1,
                    use_grid_fill=True)
            # me.update()
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()
            bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
        return{'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(SUBDIVIDE_OT_Vertexgroup)

bpy.ops.subdivide.vertexgroup()
```